# Slide next div on button click

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I'm trying to slide a div over on Button click.

I have it working by clicking on the div itself.

I've tried changing `.box` to `button` and `$(this) to $('.box')` but then all the divs seem to slide over rather than just the next div.

I'm new to jquery/javascript and have tried searching for a bunch of different solutions but I'm at a loss and I'm sure it's something very simple.

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
 $(this).animate({
  left: '-50%'
 }, 500, function() {
  $(this).css('left', '150%');
  $(this).appendTo('#slide-box-container');
 });

 $(this).next().animate({
  left: '50%'
 }, 500);
});
```

```css
#slide-box-container {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;  
}

.box {
 position: absolute;
 width: 50%;
 height: 300px;
 line-height: 300px;
 font-size: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px solid black;
 left: 50%;
 top: 100px;
 margin-left: -25%;
}

#box1 {
 background-color:#333;
 left: 50%;
}

#box2 {
 background-color:#333;
 left: 150%;
}

#box3 {
 background-color:#333;
 left: 150%;
}

#box4 {
 background-color:#333;
 left: 150%;
}

#box5 {
 background-color:#333;
 left: 150%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slide-box-container">
 <div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
 <div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
 <div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
 <div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
 <div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>
</div>

<button class="clickMe">BUTTON</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this for u. It will make it work with ur current setup.

```
<script>
var boxvar = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#box' + boxvar).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $('#box' + boxvar).css('left', '150%');
        $('#box' + boxvar).appendTo('#slide-box-container');
        if(boxvar != 5){
        boxvar += 1;
        }else{
        boxvar = 1;
        }
    });

    $('#box' + boxvar).next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wow Thank You! This makes way more sense.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :D